# concatenate columns from 2 tables in resultset

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Here is simplified version of my schema. Using Sql Server 2012 enterprise edition.

```
CREATE table #abc (a INT , b INT);  
CREATE TABLE #def ( a INT , c INT ,d INT);

INSERT INTO #abc values(1,23),(1,24);  
INSERT INTO #def VALUES(1,53,54),(1,56,57)
```

Table #abc JOINs TO #def ON COLUMN a

Basically it is concatenation of rows from both tables based on column a. Tried inner join\cross apply but they all results in cross join kind of resultset understandably . I have workaround using another temp table(then update) but kind of feel that this can be done easily in single select . I am missing something simple here.

Need output like this:

```
a   b   c   d
1   23  53  54
1   24  56  57
```

Thanks
-N

Comment: I don't see the relationship between #abc and #dbf.  How does 53 go with 23, or 56 with 24?  Is it an order thing (the first and second row in each table for value 1 map to each other)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some sort of sequence number to join the tables together.  You can generate one using `row_number()` as follows:

```
select a.a, a.b, d.c, d.d
from (select a.*, row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from #abc a
     ) a join
     (select d.*, row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from #def d
     ) d
     on a.seqnum = d.seqnum;
```

Now the caution, caution, caution.  The `order by` clause does not really specify the ordering, so the sequence numbers may not be what you expect.  You should really have a column to specify the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a unique key value in each row to be able to join the tables in the way you would like. Then, an inner join will return the result set you require.

If you introduce referential integrity between the tables, then this will be enforced and return the expected results.